# Can PowerBI be scheduled to send a GET request to an AWS API Gateway?

Tags: get, aws-lambda, powerbi, aws-api-gateway

Does PowerBI have a feature that is able to send a GET request to the AWS API Gateway? The Gateway is connected to a Lambda function that queries a AWS MySQL RDS table and send it back to PowerBI.

I don't want to directly connect PowerBI to my AWS MySQL RDS and set it as Public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

When you select Other, there is the option web. Here you can give the url and related data.

[image]

Now when having the report online you can set the automated update to once a day and it will also call the API.

Comment: Thank you @Aldert. I will install and learn PowerBI. Can it be done like every 5 minutes or less?

Comment: There is the direct query option but I am not sure if this works with web api